whatsapp's live location ratchting
I've been reading WhatsApp's white paper (titled WhatsApp Encryption Overview), but I'm having trouble understanding the ratcheting method used for live location sharing (page 16) not the ones used in double ratchet algorithm(page 9). Can anyone explain it simply?
